# Genymotion emulator not able to launch in windows 8.1

Tags: android, android-emulator, windows-8.1, genymotion

I am not able to start genimotion emulator after upgrading my windows to 8.1. It shows black screen saying dialog "Starting an emulator".

Can anyone know some work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have uninstalled every thing and install new version 2.0.1 and working fine in windows 8.1 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get mine to work by:

1. Uninstall Genymotion
2. Uninstall Virtualbox
3. Install latest Virtualbox
4. Install Genymotion (the version without Virtualbox)

Caveats: Runs slower than mollases :(   I'll post back here if I find a fix for that.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. For me it was enough to update VirtualBox to the latest available release which is version 4.18 at the time of this writing. No need to uninstall anything or to touch Genymotion itself.